# .NET Core - Where to Keep Models Shared by Multiple Repos/API?

Tags: c#, .net-core, architecture

I have the following project structure:

```
Solution
--API (serves data to front ends)
--Postgres Repository (contains connection string, methods for getting data for DB, and models)
--API Tests
```

I am now adding another repository

```
--SQL Repository
```

Models from the Postgres Repository are used by the API (via using statements). Now I will have models shared by the SQL Repository, the Postgres Repository, and the API. In the ideal world, where should these models be defined? In a separate project? In the API? Duplicated?

Edit: To give a more clear picture, we have a `Job` model. `IEnumerable<Job>` will be pulled from SQL, processed, and saved to Postgres. Where should the shared `Job` model live?

In the long term, these repositories will be used in more than one API, if that matters.

Comment: If these are entities, the can be shared across, if these are just domain models and may change per API, they should have their own version and mappers in each API.

Comment: If they are shared, where should they be defined?

Comment: Guess you need a Data repository and Implementations of each type of getting the data, Postres, sql etc. All these would be in 1 project, and share models, having their own implementations of course

Comment: May be a factory method wanting the type of Implementation that you need in whatever API you are asking for.

Comment: At the end of the day, we built a SqlRepository, PgRepository, and have a Shared project which holds any models that are used by both AND the main project. Works pretty well for us.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same classes for your API, two different data storage technologies and business logic is a road to hell. Soon you'll have attributes specific to your SQL columns, have trouble because your class has to be serializable for your API, properties that should not be saved, etc.

Use specific classes for your storage layer, you can probably share your business models between your APIs and having specific models for your APIs is a good idea too.

Single responsibility principle : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Layering : https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PresentationDomainDataLayering.html

You can use Automapper if you feel that the mapping is too much effort: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html